# relationship between .h and .c file in C

Tags: c, linker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “translation unit” in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)

> Possible duplicate:
>   [What is a "translation unit" in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)

x.h  :

```
void f();
```

x.c  :

```
void f(){}
```

main.c  :

```
#include"x.h"
int main(){
    f();
}
```

then I use:  gcc -o a.out main.c
why it say f is a undefined symbol?

Comment: The OP is trying to understand the fundamental difference between .c and .h files. IMHO, "translation unit" does not explain that.

Comment: I think the OP is actually confused about how the compiler works (i.e. he may expect that because `main.c` included `x.h` the compiler would know to look for `x.c`), but in any case there *is* a question here and it is *not* identical to the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a "translation unit" in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a linker error. You need to compile `main.c` and `x.c` at the same time, or compile them separately *without linking* and link the resulting object files.

For example:

```
gcc -o x.o -c x.c
gcc -o main.o -c main.c
gcc -o myexecutable main.o x.o
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `x.h` merely contains a declaration, which does not **define** a symbol.  `x.c` contains the definition.

Try

```
gcc -o a.out main.c x.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to include the x.h in the x.c file, and make sure that the definition is not used twice by the following code:

```
#ifndef X_H
#define X_H
f();
#endif
```

And then use gcc -o a.out main.c x.c

Answer (score 0):

Because `f` isn't defined in `x.h`, it's only declared. You need to link `x.o` into your executable. If you are not using an IDE, you might want to set up a `Makefile` to handle this, and call `make` to build your project.

Answer (score 0):

It should say this during compiling, but probably during linking.  You haven't compiled x.c yet (gcc -c x.c)?